# 「〜すぎる」と「〜まくる」はどう違いますか。

Tags: word-choice, usage, nuances, auxiliaries

**question:** Is there a difference in feeling for the words? Like すぎる feels more negative with an emphasis on disagreement with the action taken, while まくる is more about the amount?

**Examples I came across:**

> 食べすぎる
> 食べまくる
> ゲームをやりすぎる
> ゲームをやりまくる

Both pairs can be translated as ‘eating too much’ and ‘binge-playing games’ respectively (in my understanding).

**Steps taken already:**
I tried looking it up on jisho.org , but all I got was:

> まくる:  (2) to do over and over again; to do relentlessly; to do with reckless abandon​
>
> ---
>
> すぎる: to be too much, to be excessive

I also looked it up in my monolingual dictionary app and got this:

> まくる:〔動詞のあとについて〕︿しきりに＼さかんに﹀する。「書き—」
>
> ---
>
> すぎる:〔動詞・形容詞のあとについて〕 
> ①度をこす。「言い—・長—・しずか—・常識が無さ—・知らな—」
> ②〔俗〕〔ほめて〕ひじょうに…だ。「かっこよ—・すご—・美人—」
> ▽〔形容詞「ない」に続くときは語幹に「さ」をつける。「関心が なさ—」〕

These definitions seem different enough to not warrant much confusion. But I’ve seen まくる used as ‘too much’ also.

### sources:


[the jisho entry on まくる](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B)
[the jisho-entry on すぎる](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8B)
[the monolingual dictionary I used (iOS)](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/%E4%B8%89%E7%9C%81%E5%A0%82%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8-%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%83%E7%89%88-%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA/id821306606?l=en&mt=8)

Answer (score 4):

-すぎる is always negative. It means doing something *overly* or *too much*. Note that -すぎる does not necessarily mean the amount itself is large. For example, taking 2 pills a day can be 薬の飲みすぎ.

-まくる by itself is "(very) much", not "too much". It's a neutral expression that can be used both in negative and positive contexts.

Comment: So the fact that they can be translated the same way a lot of situations is purely coincidental?

Comment: @Otsukisama Actually they are so different to me that I'm not sure what you're unsure about. Everything you have cited so far shows they have different meanings and are thus translated differently. Could you give us some concrete example sentences where you believe the two are interchangeable?